# Конвертация string в uint

Tags: c#

Нашёл на стеке пример как можно конвертировать string в uint. Как я понял прямого способа нет. Вот что делаю я.

```
string str = "abc";
uint d = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString()), 0);
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Длина результирующего массива недостаточна
>   для копирования всех элементов коллекции. Проверьте индекс и длину
>   массива.'

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `string str = "abc";
            uint parsed = Convert.ToUInt32(str, 16);` не ?

Comment: Какой результат вы ожидаете получить, преобразовав строку "abc" в число?

Comment: `ToUInt32` принимает массив минимум из 4 байтов, а у вас их всего 3.

Comment: @Regent, не 6 разве?

Comment: @Андрей `UInt32` ведь состоит из 4 байтов. Плюс документация: _"Returns a 32-bit unsigned integer converted from four bytes at a specified position in a byte array."_

Comment: @Regent, я про строку вообще-то. А, пардон, туплю, там же `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`

Comment: @Андрей стоило в вопросе уточнить что вы про строку. И на всякий случай уточню, что `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` в данном случае тоже вернёт массив из 3 байтов.

Comment: @Regent в конечном итоге мне нужно получить base 64 последовательность. Извиняюсь что полностью задачу не описал. И мне нужно что бы эта строка лежала именно в 4 байтах. То есть вот как это было изначально но это не работало. `object[] mas = new object[4] { 128, 15.1, 'a', "abc" }; byte[] binData = new byte[2 + 2 + 4 + 4]; BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[0]).CopyTo(binData, 0);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[1]).CopyTo(binData, 2);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[2]).CopyTo(binData, 4);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[3]).CopyTo(binData, 8);`

Comment: Для этого я и преобразовываю в переменные соответствующих типов приведения `ushort a = Convert.ToUInt16(mas[0]);
            ushort b = Convert.ToUInt16(mas[1]);
            uint c = Convert.ToUInt32(mas[2]);
            uint d = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString()), 0);` А затем записываю в массив байт `BitConverter.GetBytes(a).CopyTo(binData, 0);` Но вот со стрингом так не получилось. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
uint x, y;

x = uint.Parse("123");

if (uint.TryParse("411", out y)) { }
```

Comment: А для строки "abc"?

Comment: Первый упадёт, второй вернёт false.